# Why is the ring of integers initial in Ring?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

In Algebra Chapter 0 Aluffi states that the ring $\Bbb{Z}$ of integers with usual addition and multiplication is initial in the category Ring. That is for a ring $R$ with identity $1_{R}$ there is a unique ring homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow{R}$ defined by $\phi(n)\mapsto{n\bullet1_{R}}$ $(\forall{n\in\Bbb{Z}})$which makes sense for rings such as $\Bbb{Q},\Bbb{R},\Bbb{C}$ which have $\Bbb{Z}$ as a subring but I fail to see how $\phi$ holds when the codomain is a ring which doesn't contain $\Bbb{Z}$. If someone could provide examples of ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Z}$ to rings other than the rings mentioned above I would appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean by $\bullet$?

Comment: Ordinary multiplication

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Surely, any ring is a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, and the dot must be multiplication by a scalar in that algebra?

Comment: Well, what excatly is «ordinary multiplication» in this context? If $R$ does not contain $\mathbb Z$, then there is no ordinary multiplication to speak of thatwill multiply $1?R$ by $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, I know. I am trying to have the OP realize what exactly that means (notice that «any ring is a $\mathbb Z$-algebra» is precisely the statement the OP has problems with...)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ah, that makes sense. Sorry I didn't catch on.

Comment: $n 1_R$ for $n\in\mathbf{N}$ simply means $0$ if $n=0$, $\sum_{i=1}^n 1_R$ if $n>0$, and the opposite if $n<0$.

Comment: The initial object need not be a subobject of every object in a category.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In every ring (with unit) $R$ you have a $1$. And you have thus $1+1$, and $1+1+1$, &c. You can consider the collection of all these elements and their additive inverses, $-(1+1), -(1+1+1)$, &c. For $n>0$ call these elements $n1$ and set $(-n)1=-(n1)$, if $n=0$; $n1=0$. You should convince yourself that $m1+n1=(m+n)1$ for any pair of integers $n,m$, and $n1\cdot m1=(nm)1$. Of course $1\cdot 1=1$. This means the collection of such elements is a subring of $R$. It looks like $\Bbb Z$, since every element is just a sum of $1$ (or difference), but note that these elements needn't be distinct. For example, in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, $2\cdot 1=-1\cdot 1$.

At any rate, now we can define a function $f:\Bbb Z\to R$ for any ring $R$ with unit that sends the integer $n$ to $n1$, as defined above. What you checked above is precisely the claim that $f(n)f(m)=f(mn)$ and $f(n+m)=f(n)+f(m)$, $f(1)=1$. This means $f$ is a morphism of rings. Since $R$ was arbitrary, we have shown that every ring $R$ admits a morphism of rings $f:\Bbb Z \to R$.

It remains to see that $f$ is unique. Now if $g:\Bbb Z\to R$ is another morphism of rings, we know that $g(1)=1$ (i.e. $g$ sends the unit of $\Bbb Z$ to the unit of $R$), hence $g(-1)=-1$ (why?). But any nonzero integer is $n$ is $1+\dots+1$ ($n$ times) or $-1-\cdots-1$ ($n$ times), so using $g$ is $\Bbb Z$-linear ($g(a+b)=g(a)+g(b)$) gives $g$ sends $n$ to $f(n)$ as defined above, i.e. $f=g$.

Comment: It's true that $g$ is linear, but given the nature of this question I think it should probably be demonstrated or justified.

Comment: Or rather perhaps the word should be homomorphism.

Comment: @MattSamuel I mean $g(a)+g(b)=g(a+b)$.

Comment: In my language linear would also imply $g(n\cdot a)=n\cdot g(a)$.

Comment: @MattSamuel $\Bbb Z$-linear. =)

Answer (score 3):

Take the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (also known as $\mathrm{GF}_2$) with two elements, and define $$\phi(n)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\0&\text{if $n$ is even}\end{cases}$$
To learn something from this example, prove that this is the only homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Any such morphism $f$ satisfies $f(n)=f(\sum_{i=1}^n 1) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(1) = \sum_{i=1}^n 1_R = n 1_R$. You have the unicity. The existence is trivial, just define it this way, by the previous formula. So you have the definition for *any* ring $R$ with unit. ;-) Note that the image of $\mathbf{Z}$ is always in $R$'s center.

*Remark.* $n 1_R$ for $n\in\mathbf{N}$ simply means $0$ if $n=0$, $\sum_{i=1}^n 1_R$ if $n>0$, and the opposite if $n<0$. I precise this as I think that *this* is the only thing bothering you.

Comment: Notice that this does not answer the question asked!

Comment: I know, but nowadays I have to answer before finishing and then edit to finish, as sometimes I loose everything with bad keyboard combinations... Happened me once with a long answer...

Comment: «there is a unique morphism of ring $\mathbb Z\to R$, and this because the image of Z is in R's center» That is very weird: you cannot justify the existence of a morphism by saying that its image in in $R$'s center! OTOH, the formula you gave only works for positive $n$.

Comment: Which I dit not say. I say that there's one, and that in fact there's only one.

Comment: Ah ok I see, lemme edit, forgot to erase.